# In Magento1.x we see multiple errors from Amasty SeoShortUrl plugin whenever there is "?___SID=U" in URL

Tags: magento-1.9

In error.log & access.log

```
2021/02/15 11:49:19 [error] 7429#7429: *11059097 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP 

Fatal error:  Call to a member function **getAttributeCode**() on boolean in 
httpdocs/includes/src/Amasty_SeoShortUrl_Helper_Attributes.php 
on line 119" while reading response header from upstream, client: 152.115.137.98, 
server: www.example.com, 
request: "GET /herreure?___SID=U HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.sock:",
 host: "www.example.com", 
referrer: "https://www.example.com/borneure"
```

Comment: an your question is? :)

Comment: My question is why i am facing this error "Call to a member function **getAttributeCode**() on boolean in 
httpdocs/includes/src/Amasty_SeoShortUrl_Helper_Attributes.php"

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have access to the code of this particular 3rd party module, from what I can see in the error and how the URL is formatted, I think the module 'identifies' the `'<something>=<something_else>'` in the URL as being an `'attribute=value'` and tries to probably convert it in a SEO friendly URL.

I would suggest you contact the Amasty team for this and see if they can provide a fix.